# Como montar um select apartir do DB

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, pessoal minha duvida e a seguinte tenho um banco de dados que me lista todos as datas de entrega de trabalhos da seguinte forma

```
2016-07-13
2016-07-01
2016-03-09
2015-09-09
2013-03-06
```

como faço para montar duas selects que contenha apenas os dados da tabela

sendo a de ano

```
2016
2015
2014
```

e a de mes de acordo com o ano selecionado e apenas com os mes que contenha naquele ano

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando vc diz montar `select` se refere aquele `select` do html?

Comment: isso mesmo ate adicionei uma imagem para ficar mais claro a pergunta

Comment: Legal, agora ficou mais clara a situação. Tem várias coisas  p fazer, o roterio é, 1) faça um select no banco apenas retornando a coluna data use a função `year()` para extrair o ano lembre de agrupar, assim vc tem a lista de anos com entrega. 2) Com javascript faça um chamada ajax no `onchange()` do combo de ano e envie o valor do item selecionado. 3) esse valor vai no `where`(com `year()`) feito a consulta pega o resultado do ajax e popule o combo de mês com os valores.

Comment: Para pegar o mês `SELECT to_char(dia, 'MM') FROM tabela WHERE to_char(dia, 'YYYY') = '2016' GROUP BY to_char(dia, 'MM')` e para pegar o ano `SELECT to_char(dia, 'YYYY') FROM tabela GROUP BY to_char(dia, 'YYYY')`.

Comment: Valeu pessoal vou montar aqui tem um código ajax para cidades estado vou usar ele como base